# How to prevent writing 'object' field in PaperTrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem, papertrail-app

1. I have many fields in my table, I don't want to version all columns.
   How do I skip the columns which I don't need to store any changes

I have used the following, but it stores the values in 'versions' table.
In my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail skip: [:foo1, :foo2, :foo3]
  # tried with ignore instead of skip
end
```

2. How do I prevent writing object field in 'versions' table.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. ... I don't want to version all columns. How do I skip the columns which I don't need to store any changes

`skip` is correct. In the docs, see [Section 2.c. Choosing Attributes To Monitor](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#2c-choosing-attributes-to-monitor):

> You can skip fields altogether with the :skip option. As with :ignore, updates to these fields will not create a new PaperTrail::Version. In addition, these fields will not be included in the serialized version of the object whenever a new PaperTrail::Version is created.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_paper_trail :skip => [:file_upload]
> end
> ```

If `skip` is not working the way it's documented, please submit a bug report.

Re: your second question:

> 2. How do I prevent writing object field in 'versions' table.

When inserting records into `versions`, PaperTrail always writes *something* in the `object` column. You can configure *what* is written, e.g. with `skip`, but it will always write *something*.